# Sidebar won't autogenerate with docs multi-instances on Docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

I'm sure I'm making some stupid basic error here, but I cannot get the sidebar to autogenerate for my second docs instance.

I've followed the guide here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance#setup

For reference, by config look like this:

```
  plugins: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs',
      {
        id: `execution`,
        path: './execution',
        routeBasePath: 'execution',
        sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebarsExecution.js'),
      },
      ],
    ],
```

I've created an additional `sidebarsExecution.js` file for the second docs instance that looks like this:

```
export default {
  executionSidebar: [
    {
      type: 'autogenerated',
      dirName: '../execution',
    },
  ],
};
```

But I keep getting this error:

`[WARNING] No docs found in "../execution": can't auto-generate a sidebar.`

I've tried `./execution` and just `execution` without luck.

Comment: are you sure `execution` folder is in same directory as docusaurus.config.js?

Comment: I see the same on my instance. Doesn't matter if I use absolute or relative paths, it's failing to load.